# Issue with calculation code in JSP / JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

Hope you can help me with this one :(
Right ... I am trying to calculate the ticket costs but it only shows the first two digits and it ignores the decimals, as well as it replaces the decimals with .00

code within a JavaBean:

```
        ticketCosts.put(results.getString(1), Double.valueOf(results.getInt(2)));
```

---

Any ideas, would help ... thanks :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
   ticketCosts.put(results.getString(1), Double.valueOf(results.getInt(2)))
```

use getDouble method of resultset

```
 ticketCosts.put(results.getString(1), results.getDouble(2))
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble(int)

Comment: can I also ask you something ... ?!  pm ?!

Comment: ... would it be possible to remove the whole code from the BEAN, and only do so it works from the .jsp file itself?!

Comment: Yes, but that is not a good approach to code your web application. You place getAllTicketCosts() function inside a class file (specialised to retrieve ticket data from database) to separate this logic from other code and reuse it any time.

Comment: yes, I understand you ... but can you guide me in doing that way?! would appreciate it a lot

Comment: You just need to copy and paste those code from  getAllTicketCosts() function and database connection code and paste it inside a JSP file.
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=619
Here is the guide

Comment: LOL now I got lots of errors ... :/

I was thinking more, a less coding method but yeh coding is not my strongest part :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but for Money do NOT use Double, you will end up with rounding errors.

Use BigDecimal instead.

See
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal